# SOL program to Lock SPL Token for short period

Tags: solana-program, transactions, spl-token, wallet, transfer

I am looking for way to hold/lock/pledge/promise a fixed amount of tokens from a sender, and later in about few hours or days later transfer those to some recipients.
Can we achieve this while keeping SOL tokens in senders wallet? Or what recommended ways there is to achieve above.
(Reason for above lock/pledge an amount is to ensure fund is available when the transfer happens)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the bonfida token vesting program for this: https://vesting.bonfida.org/ , https://github.com/Bonfida/token-vesting

Comment: This means we have to take the tokens out from wallet to solana program/account owned by us(product offering team) ? Is there any solution to lock while keep the tokens in wallet.

Comment: Are the tokens really locked if you keep them in your wallet since you can just transfer them out from the wallet anytime?

Comment: True, Forgive me, im still getting used to this. So I guess you are talking about moving the tokens to a PDA?

Comment: No worries, sorry, i realized my previous reply probably sounded a bit sarcastic. Yes, i believe that's how the bonfida token vesting program works in a nutshell - the tokens are transferred to a token account that's controlled by a PDA.